# prediction interval for multiple linear regression in r. Why results show multiple rows?

Tags: r, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I am running a multi-linear regression in R. And I want to add 3 to all the rows for column named "educ", then find out the 99% confidence interval for this predicted change.
here are my codes:

```
reg5 = lm(sleep ~ educ + age + gdhlth + smsa + union + selfe +
     marr + yrsmarr + yngkid, data = data)
newdata = data
newdata$educ = newdata$educ + 3
keeps <- c('educ', 'age', 'gdhlth','smsa', 'union','selfe' ,
    'marr', 'yrsmarr','yngkid')
newdata = newdata[keeps]
predict(reg5, newdata = newdata, interval = 'prediction', level=0.99)
```

And my results are having over 300 rows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jLSX.png)
Can anyone help to look at why I can't get a simple confidence interval?

Comment: It is finding the confidence interval for prediction in every row in the data frame.  You probably one to create a new data frame with just the values for education which you are looking for and not the 300 in the original data.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg